# How to use `postUpdate` in CRUD controllers?

Tags: php, sonata-admin, symfony

I've installed `SonataAdminBundle` and created custom CRUD controller for one entity. I want to perform some action after entity updated. How can I achieve this using CRUD controller's? I've noticed, that `Admin*` classes have `preUpdate` and `postUpdate` methods for such purpose, I could use them, but I guess, that logic should be placed in controllers.

The easiest way I see it's rewriting `editAction` (override this method in my controller, copy/paste code from base `CRUDController` and add calling own `postUpdate`), but copy/paste it's bad:) Maybe I missed some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you review code written in sonata admin's `editAction()` in `CRUDController` you can see its calling admin's `update()` method.

```
$object = $this->admin->update($object);
```

you can review `update()` method in sonata base admin class before calling model manager to persist object it has a `preUpdate()` call and same case for `postUpdate()` after calling model manager.

That means the one you are trying to implement `pre` or `post` actions for your entity you have to write your own logic but the question is why you want to redo or rewrite any available action ? you can use already provided `pre` or `post` hooks.

Comment: "pre or post hooks" - you mean entity lifecycle events?

Comment: @SergeyChizhik by pre/post hooks in regards of admin class i mean preUpdate and posUpdate

Comment: Got it. Actually I can, but I've just thought that admin classes should know just about how entities will be presented and all behavior should be placed to controllers.